# How 'indexer' is working in this example?

Tags: c#, .net

This is the main class

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyArray fruit = new MyArray(-2, 1);
        fruit[-2] = "Apple";
        fruit[-1] = "Orange";
        fruit[0] = "Banana";
        fruit[1] = "Blackcurrant";
        Console.WriteLine(fruit[-1]);       // Outputs "Orange"
        Console.WriteLine(fruit[0]);        // Outputs "Banana"
        Console.WriteLine(fruit[-1,0]);     // Output "O"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and here is the class for the indexer:

```
class MyArray
{
    int _lowerBound;
    int _upperBound;
    string[] _items;

    public MyArray(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
    {
        _lowerBound = lowerBound;
        _upperBound = upperBound;
        _items = new string[1 + upperBound - lowerBound];
    }

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return _items[index - _lowerBound]; }
        set { _items[index - _lowerBound] = value; }

    }

    public string this[int word, int position]
    {
        get { return _items[word - _lowerBound].Substring(position, 1); }
    }
}
```

So, multiDimensional indexer in defined in the 'Class MyArray'

I am not able to understand how this is working when we pass '-1' as the value of 'word' to the indexer. The value for '_lowerbound' is '-2'. So it means, the value for the return should be _items[-1 - (-2)], which makes it _items[1].

But actually it is pointing to -1 index of fruits i.e. Orange.

Please clear my doubt.

Comment: I dont understand your doubt. What are you expecting?

Comment: what is multi-dimensional here? `MyArray` is a 1 dimensional array of `string` with a flexible base.

Comment: -1 index of fruits is stored in 1 index of _items. The indexer translates the index into fruits, which is based on _lowerBound and could be 0-based, 1-based, or based on some other positive or negative integer, into an index on _items, which is 0-based like all arrays in C#.

Comment: Both of the indexers are consistently applying `- _lowerBound` to any provided index position. So anything accessed via `[-1]` will be the same thing accessed via `[-1,...]`.

Comment: @Jodrell By multi-dimensional indexer the OP means the indexer which takes two parameters.

Comment: MultiDimensional Indexer : public string this[int word, int position]

Comment: @Mohit What do you expect the call `fruits[-1, 0]` to return and why?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth `fruit[-1, 0]` returns "O". See the code at the top of the question.

Comment: @DavidConrad Seriously... I read the question, did you read my comment? The OP seems confused as to **why** Orange is returned, hence I was asking what he expected - which isn't stated. If we can understand the expectation and the reasoning he places behind it, we can understand where the confusion comes in.

Comment: Yes, the OP is confused, but the OP is even confused as to why plain old fruit[-1] returns "Orange".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is you private array `_items`:

```
   0     1     2     3
┌────┐┌────┐┌────┐┌────┐
│ Ap ││ Or ││ Ba ││ Bl │          
└────┘└────┘└────┘└────┘
```

This is how it appears using the indexer:

```
  -2    -1     0     1
┌────┐┌────┐┌────┐┌────┐
│ Ap ││ Or ││ Ba ││ Bl │          
└────┘└────┘└────┘└────┘
```

> The value for `_lowerbound` is `-2`.
>
> So it means, the value for the return should be `_items[-1 - (-2)]`, which makes it `_items[1]`.

That's correct.

> But actually it is pointing to `-1` index of fruits i.e. Orange.

That's wrong. It is pointing to `_items[1]`, i.e. Orange.

Indexers are a simple way to permit a class to be used like an array. Internally, you can manage the values presented in any fashion you wish.

`_items` is a zero-based array with the same length as the created `MyArray` object.

The indexer is just interpreting the index number supplied and map it against this underlying array.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>This isn't a multi-dimensional array [in the expected sense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), it just looks like one.</sub>

**Updated Answer:**

It looks like you expect: `fruits[-1, 0]` to point to the same element as `fruits[1] = "Blackcurrent"`. Unfortunately this isn't the case as in both instances you are actually using custom indexers, both of which modify your provided index values.

The custom indexers on `MyArray` are *mutating* the index values you are supplying *before* they get to the underlying `string[]`. This is where the confusion has come in, you are not taking into account the code in the custom indexers:

```
public string this[int index]
{
    get { return _items[index - _lowerBound]; }
    set { _items[index - _lowerBound] = value; }

}

public string this[int word, int position]
{
    get { return _items[word - _lowerBound].Substring(position, 1); }
}
```

---

**Old Answer:**

Don't confuse array index in primitive arrays with indexing on **custom implementations**. You can do whatever you like with the latter, it is basically just syntactic sugar over method calls. You have an indexer that takes an `int`, that means any valid `int` is a valid argument for the indexer (though maybe not for the underlying primitive array `string[]`).

Your index implementation subtracts `lowerBound` from both the get and the set, so the same index supplied at the set will result in the same element as the index supplied for the get.

The second indexer taking two parameters is doing the *same* index modification so will result in the *same* element (Orange)...

Where is the confusion? Are you expecting the second parameter of...

```
public string this[int word, int position]
```

...to somehow affect what element is returned? It is used in the `Substring` call of the element returned by the ordinal `word - lowerBound`, it does *not* affect what element is chosen.

Comment: It seems the sugar is a little too sweet in this case.

Comment: i had confusion on this and is clear now: in the above example in the main function, Console.writeline(fruit[-1,0]), we are passing '-1' as the value for 'word' parameter to the index. The resultant return value should be : _fruits[-1 - (-2)], which is _fruits[1]. If we look at array fruits, at the index 1, we have 'Blackcurrant'. But the output was "O" as it actually pointed to Orange. As, @lesderid and Maarten explained it that the .net array index starts from 0, so this means that _fruits[1] should point to "Orange". Apple is the  first value of the index i.e. 0.

Comment: i was EXPECTING that this index should work the way it is defined i.e. it should start from -2 instead of .net array index 0.

Comment: @Mohit "_fruits[-1 - (-2)], which is _fruits[1]" - this is incorrect. The modification happens *after* the `fruits` indexer has been called, this is more accurate: `_items[-1 - (-2)]`, which is `_items[1]`.

Comment: @Mohit But it **does** work the way it is defined. If you specify `_fruits[-2]` you get "Apple"... you are confusing array-style access on **custom indexers** to array access on primitive .NET arrays, where the index implementation is **not custom**. `_fruits` is **not** a primitive array.

Comment: oops, sorry in my previous reply, i mean _items[-1 - (-2)], _items[1] not _fruits[1].

Answer (score 1):

The index calculated in this[int] and this[int,int] is the index as you need it in the _items array, and this array starts at index 0. So the second item there is indeed index=1, which is Orange.

Update:
_items[-1] doesn't exist, this array starts at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in .Net languages, like C#, can't have items with negative indexes.

To circumvent this, this array class moves the item with the lowest index (index of `_lowerBound`) to 0. So when you access the internal array, you'll have to substract `_lowerBound` from the index, so it will never try to pass a negative index.

This is why -1 will actually be at 1 in the internal array, because -1 - (-2) equals to 1.

Edit: I'm not sure why you think there should be a difference between your class' two indexers. They both use `_items[index - _lowerBound]` to access the underlying .Net array.
Other than the String.Substring call, there's no difference between the two indexers.

Try changing the code of the second indexer so it calls the first indexer, you'll see it returns the same character. (http://ideone.com/sFmDo)

Comment: But this is custom indexer logic and entering a negative value into a primitive .NET array (such as `string[]`) throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I'm not sure I understand what you are getting at here.

Comment: It will never actually pass a negative index to the .Net array, as long as the index isn't lower than _lowerBound. It's basically just moving the bounds.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I think the OP does too - there seems to be some confusion over wanting the index value to mean something different for one of the indexers, and something else for the other indexer.

Comment: I don't think anyone is really sure :-)

Comment: I don't think the OP wrote the code; instead, the OP is asking for an explanation to try to understand the code.

Comment: Alright, if i pass '-2' for word it will be _items[-2 - (-2)] i.e. _items[0]  and the .net arrays start index from '0'. Hence, it will point to 'Apple'.

Comment: Ya, i read this tutorial about c# indexers on Blackwasp.co.uk. I was confused about this MultiDimensional indexer. Now, my doubt is clear.